# Change the order of lines in a file

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line

I'm trying to change the order of lines in a specific pattern. Working with a file with many lines (ex. 99 lines). For every three lines, I would like the second line to be the third line, and the third to be the second line.

EXAMPLE.

**1- Input:**

```
gi_1234
My cat is blue.
I have a cat.
gi_5678
My dog is orange.
I also have a dog.
...
```

**2- Output:**

```
gi_1234
I have a cat.
My cat is blue.
gi_5678
I also have a dog.
My dog is orange.
...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `awk` and integer maths:

```
awk 'NR%3 == 1 { print } NR%3 == 2 { delay=$0 } NR%3 == 0 { print; print delay; delay=""} END { if(length(delay) != 0 ) { print delay } }' /path/to/input
```

The modulus operator performs integer division and returns the remainder, so for each line, it will return the sequence 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0 [...].  Knowing that, we just save the input on lines where the modulus is 2 for later -- to wit, just after printing the input when it's zero.

Comment: We've a small flaw here. See my answer, minor improvement part

Comment: Thanks for the good catch; I have incorporated a fix into my answer in the form of `NR%3 == 0 { print; print delay; delay=""} END { if(length(delay) != 0 ) { print delay }`.

Answer (score 23):

```
$ seq 9 | sed -n 'p;n;h;n;G;p'
1
3
2
4
6
5
7
9
8
```

That is, `p`rint the current line, get the `n`ext one, `h`old it, get the `n`ext one, `G`et the held line (append it to the pattern space) and `p`rint that 2-line pattern space with the third and second lines swapped.

Answer (score 3):

Another ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '{print $0; if ((getline L2)>0 && (getline L3)>0){ print L3 ORS L2 }}' file
```

The output:

```
gi_1234
I have a cat.
My cat is blue.
gi_5678
I also have a dog.
My dog is orange.
```

---

- `(getline L2)>0 && (getline L3)>0` - extracts next ***2*** records if they exist
- each 2nd and 3rd records are assigned to `L2` and `L3` variables respectively

Comment: I'm assuming those variables start with the letter L (lower case). They are poor choices for readability because they look like the numerals for twelve and thirteen. A better choice might be `line2`, etc.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, changed to uppercase

Answer (score 3):

Using `perl` and a short script:

```
user@pc:~$ cat input.txt 
gi_1234
My cat is blue.
I have a cat.
gi_5678
My dog is orange.
I also have a dog.

user@pc:~$ perl -ne '$l2=<>; $l3=<>; print $_,$l3,$l2;' input.txt 
gi_1234
I have a cat.
My cat is blue.
gi_5678
I also have a dog.
My dog is orange.
```

The script process the whole file, for each line (stored in `$_`) it will get the next two lines (`$l2` and `$l3`) and print them in the requested order: line1, line3, line2.

Answer (score 3):

#### Perl

```
perl -ne 'print if $.%3==1;$var=$_ if $.%3==2;print $_ . $var if $.%3==0' input.txt
```

The idea here is that we use modulo operator `%` with line number `$.` variable, to figure out which one is every first, which one is every second, and which one is every 3rd line. For every 3rd line remainder is 0, while for every 1st and 2nd line it will have corresponding numbers.

Test:

```
$ cat input.txt                                                                                                          
gi_1234
My cat is blue.
I have a cat.
gi_5678
My dog is orange.
I also have a dog.

$ perl -ne 'print if $.%3==1;$var=$_ if $.%3==2;print $_ . $var if $.%3==0' input.txt                                    
gi_1234
I have a cat.
My cat is blue.
gi_5678
I also have a dog.
My dog is orange.
```

#### Minor improvement

The approach with storing second line into a variable has a flaw. What if the last line is the "second" one , i.e. for that line number remainder is 2 ? The original code in my and DopeGhoti's answer won't print `My dog is orange` if we leave out the last line. The fix for that in both cases is to use `END{}` code block, with unsetting the temporary variable after printing. In other words:

```
$ awk 'NR%3 == 1 { print } NR%3 == 2 { delay=$0 } NR%3 == 0 { print; print delay;delay=""}END{print delay}' input.txt
```

and

```
$ perl -ne '$s=$_ if $.%3==2;print $_ . $s and $s="" if $.%3==0 or $.%3==1;END{print $s}' input.txt
```

This way, the code will work for arbitrary number of lines in a file, not just those divisible by 3.

#### Additional fix for issue mentioned in comments

In awk's case, if the last line in the file produces output of 1 for $. % 3, the previous code has issue of outputting blank newline  because of unconditional printing of `END{print delay}`, since `print` function mentioned in the comments always appends newline to whatever variable it is operating on.  In case of `perl` version this issue doesn't occur, since with `-ne` flags `print` function doesn't append the newline.

Nonetheless, the fix in awk's case is to make conditional, as mentioned by Dope Ghoti in the comments is to verify the length of the temporary variable. The perl version of the same fix would be:

```
$ perl -ne '$s=$_ if $.%3==2;print $_ . $s and $s="" if $.%3==0 or $.%3==1;END{print $s if length $s}' input.txt
```

Comment: Your fix has a potential minor flaw of its own in that it will append a blank line of output for files with the 'wrong' number of lines.  I have fixed this in my incorporation of your improvement in my answer with (for `awk`) `NR%3 == 0 { print; print delay; delay=""} END { if(length(delay) != 0 ) { print delay }`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti The issue doesn't occur with perl, since perl's print with `-ne` flags doesn't output a newline.  It does indeed print, but it's a null string, no trailing newline. Nontheless, I've added the mention of the issue and the same fix into my answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make a while loop? In expanded form:

```
( while read a
  do
    read b
    read c
    echo "$a"
    echo "$c"
    echo "$b"
  done
) < input.txt
```

In "single line format":

```
( while read a ; do read b ; read c ; echo "$a" ; echo "$c" ; echo "$b" ; done) < input.txt
```

Outputs:

```
gi_1234
I have a cat.
My cat is blue.
gi_5678
I also have a dog.
My dog is orange.
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be as follows:

```
sed -e '
   /\n/s/\(.*\)\(\n\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/;//b
   $!N;$q;N;                            # load up the pattern space with 3 lines provided eof not reached
   P;D;                                 # first just print the first line then interchange the two and print them
' yourfile
```

Alternatively,

```
perl -ne 'print $_, reverse scalar <>, scalar <>' yourfile
```

---

### Results

```
gi_1234
I have a cat.
My cat is blue.
gi_5678
I also have a dog.
My dog is orange.
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Vim

Not suitable for long files, but still handy if you were just editing a file and wanted, for example, to reorder some yaml stanzas.

First record a macro:

```
gg qq j ddp j q
```

And then repeat desired number of times:

```
@q @q @q ...
```

Or just e.g.

```
3@q
```

Explanation:

- gg - go to the first line
- qq - start recording a macro
- j - go to the second line
- ddp - swap the second and the third line
- j - go to the fourth line, i.e. to the first of the next three lines
- q - stop recording
- @q - replay the macro once
- 3@q - replay the macro three times

Comment: Instead manual repeating `@q @q @q`, it is possible doing by this way `3@q` - repeat three times. `100@q` - repeat the macro 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

**Usage:** `./shuffle_lines.awk input.txt`

Check shebang `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`, because the `awk` location may differ on your system.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    if ((NR + 1) % 3 == 0) {
        buffer = $0;
    } else if (NR % 3 == 0) {
        print $0 ORS buffer;
        buffer = "";
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some one-liner transformations, I like to use [`pyp`](https://pypi.org/project/pypyp/) (distributed as "pypyp").

For this particular task:

- `$ seq 9 | pyp '[elem for group in zip(lines[0::3],lines[2::3],lines[1::3]) for elem in group]'`

Shorter example output looks like this:

```
$ seq 6 | pyp '[elem for group in zip(lines[0::3],lines[2::3],lines[1::3]) for elem in group]'
1
3
2
4
6
5
```

And pyp's `--explain` flag can help show what's happening:

```
$ seq 9 | pyp --explain '[elem for group in zip(lines[0::3],lines[2::3],lines[1::3]) for elem in group]'
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from pyp import pypprint
lines = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in sys.stdin]
output = [elem for group in zip(lines[0::3], lines[2::3], lines[1::3]) for elem in group]
if output is not None:
    pypprint(output)
```

Pyp supports customization through a `PYP_CONFIG_FILE`.

pyp performs static analysis of the input code, some AST transformations and pruning, then compiles and executes the result, or with `--explain`, unparses the AST back to source. It imports packages from its environment, and errors early on unknown or undefined symbols.

See other examples at https://pypi.org/project/pypyp/.