# Swap lines in a file

Tags: linux, text-processing

I've a file like this:

```
DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
dn: cn=311999,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
dn: cn=948089,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
dn: cn=947458,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

DelegatedAdmin: cn=9776c3f8-f2ee-4b6c-a9a9-32d87b45f7c5,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
dn: cn=10717,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

DelegatedAdmin: cn=e0a838f0-3d53-42e8-8dad-bd1d774381de,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
dn: cn=1500,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
```

And it should be changed to this (switching line 1 and line 4)

```
dn: cn=311999,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

dn: cn=948089,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

dn: cn=947458,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

dn: cn=10717,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
DelegatedAdmin: cn=9776c3f8-f2ee-4b6c-a9a9-32d87b45f7c5,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

dn: cn=1500,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
DelegatedAdmin: cn=e0a838f0-3d53-42e8-8dad-bd1d774381de,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
```

How to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the order of lines in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368418/change-the-order-of-lines-in-a-file)

Comment: Yes it does thx

Answer (score 6):

Try also

```
awk '{print $4, $2, $3, $1}' RS= FS="\n" OFS="\n" ORS="\n\n"  file
dn: cn=311999,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
```

using the `RS=<empty>` for multiline records separated by an empty line, the field separator `<NL>` to make lines = fields, and then just printing those in the desired order.

Comment: Thx it works :)

Comment: Can you add, what the command does?

Answer (score 4):

Taking a different tack, you could use `ed` to **m**ove the `DelegatedAdmin:` lines down 3 and the `dn:` lines up 3:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^DelegatedAdmin:/m+3' 'g/^dn:/m-3' 'w newfile' 'q' | ed -s file
```

Change `'w newfile' 'q'` to plain `'wq'` to edit `file` in place. Testing to standard out:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/^DelegatedAdmin:/m+3' 'g/^dn:/m-3' ',p' 'Q' | ed -s file
dn: cn=311999,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

dn: cn=948089,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

dn: cn=947458,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

dn: cn=10717,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
DelegatedAdmin: cn=9776c3f8-f2ee-4b6c-a9a9-32d87b45f7c5,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

dn: cn=1500,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
changetype: modify<br />
delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
DelegatedAdmin: cn=e0a838f0-3d53-42e8-8dad-bd1d774381de,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
```

Comment: Very nice ed solution. =)

Comment: @ForeverCuber thanks - tbh I'd probably end up using awk irl, but it's fun to play with the less popular tools sometimes

Comment: When awk is too popular for your tastes... :)

Answer (score 3):

You might find a better answer in the existing thread:
[Change the order of lines in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368418/change-the-order-of-lines-in-a-file)

There are some really good answers there, it seems.
This may not help if you need this done "in place"; but I extrapolated the following solution from there using `Perl`:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368429/344329

> The script process the whole file, for each line (stored in $_) it will get the next two lines ($l2 and $l3) and print them in the requested order: line1, line3, line2.

The solution there is:

```
perl -ne '$l2=<>; $l3=<>; print $_,$l3,$l2;' input.txt
```

For your use case you might try something like this:

```
perl -ne '$l2=<>; $l3=<>; $l4=<>; $l5=<>; print $l4,$l2,$l3,$_,$l5; if(eof) { exit; } ' input.txt >> output.txt
```

To be transparent: I am no expert, so I am not confident this is the best way for you.

Comment: Thx it works :)

Answer (score 3):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

[Adds extra blank line at end]:

```perl
raku -ne 'my ($L1,$L2,$L3,$L4) = (get) xx 4; .put for $L3, $L1, $L2, $_, ($L4 // "");'   

#OR

raku -e 'my @a.=push($_) if .chars for lines; put($_ ~ "\n") for @a.rotor(4)>>.[3,1,2,0]>>.join("\n");'
```

[Doesn't add extra blank line at end]:

```perl
raku -ne 'my ($L1,$L2,$L3,$L4) = (get) xx 4; .put for $L3, $L1, $L2, $_; $L4.defined ?? $L4.put !! next;' 

#OR

raku -e 'my @a.=push($_) if .chars for lines; .put for @a.rotor(4)>>.[3,1,2,0]>>.join("\n").join("\n\n");'
```

First and third examples are similar to Perl5 code posted by @ForeverCuber, and bears a vague resemblance to `awk` code posted by @RudiC. First/third examples use `-ne` commandline flags. Second/fourth examples push `line`s onto an `@`-sigiled array.

For the first example the `-ne` commandline flags means the first line loads into `$_`, Raku's topic variable. Raku is instructed to `get` 4 successive lines, which load into each of `($L1,$L2,$L3,$L4)`. The Record Separator is represented by `$L4` which, when undefined (at end), is handled using Raku's `//` defined-OR operator. Thus `""` blank string is out`put` if left-side of `//` evaluates to undefined. Printing is simplified without any `join`s and by the use of `put` only.

Second example `push`es `line`s onto an array, `@a`. Blank lines are skipped via the conditional `if .chars`. Array elements are `rotor`ed together (grouped into 4-element sublists/records), reordered with `[3,1,2,0]` indexing, and `join`ed with one call to `join("\n")`. Printing of records is simplified by use of `put($_ ~ "\n")`, which demonstrates that string concatenation is accomplished via `~` tilde in Raku.

Third example is similar to first example in that it uses `-ne` commandline flags, and again, no `join`s are used. However undefined last line is handled better by Raku's "Test `??` True `!!` False" ternary operator (i.e. `$L4.defined ?? $L4.put !! next;`). Thus no extra blank line is added at the end. Note: `print ""` could be used here, in place of `next`.

Fourth example is similar to second example, except out`put` is built up by two successive calls to `join`, which recreates the original record spacing (and no extra blank line is added at the end). The first `>>.join("\n")` call maps into the `rotor`ed record to join the 4 lines into a single array element. The second `.join("\n\n")` takes the resultant 5 array elements (records) and joins them with a blank space in-between each, recreating the input but with the desired line-ordering.

---

Sample Input (lines have been numbered):

```
1 DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
2 changetype: modify<br />
3 delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
4 dn: cn=311999,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

5 DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
6 changetype: modify<br />
7 delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
8 dn: cn=948089,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

9 DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
10 changetype: modify<br />
11 delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
12 dn: cn=947458,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

13 DelegatedAdmin: cn=9776c3f8-f2ee-4b6c-a9a9-32d87b45f7c5,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
14 changetype: modify<br />
15 delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
16 dn: cn=10717,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

17 DelegatedAdmin: cn=e0a838f0-3d53-42e8-8dad-bd1d774381de,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
18 changetype: modify<br />
19 delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
20 dn: cn=1500,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
```

Sample Output:

```
4 dn: cn=311999,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
2 changetype: modify<br />
3 delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
1 DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

8 dn: cn=948089,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
6 changetype: modify<br />
7 delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
5 DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

12 dn: cn=947458,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
10 changetype: modify<br />
11 delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
9 DelegatedAdmin: cn=fb6190f7-4a33-4502-a2d5-dce8dc434570,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

16 dn: cn=10717,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
14 changetype: modify<br />
15 delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
13 DelegatedAdmin: cn=9776c3f8-f2ee-4b6c-a9a9-32d87b45f7c5,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />

20 dn: cn=1500,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
18 changetype: modify<br />
19 delete: DelegatedAdmin<br />
17 DelegatedAdmin: cn=e0a838f0-3d53-42e8-8dad-bd1d774381de,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault<br />
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/^Delegate/{N;N;N;s/\(.*\)\(\n.*\n.*\n\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/;}'
```

Or, making use of the hold space:

```
sed -ne '/^Delegate/{h;n;N;G;x;n;G;}' -e p
```

Answer (score 0):

`perl`  one liner

```bsh
perl -lne '
  print reverse $_, /./ ? (<>.<>, $,.<>) : ();
' file
```

- `-n` reads files line by line and the line is held inside the `$_` variable.
- the builtin `reverse` in a list context, as is provided in the print statement, the arguments are reversed.
- the next lineis accessed by the diamond operator `<>` and it includes the newline.
- so we have the order of reverse arguments list as:

  - 1   2  3        4
  - $_ (<>.<>), ("".<>)
  - outputs:
    _     4     2  3    1
  - ("".<>), (<>.<>), $_
- please be aware that reverse cannot peek inside of brackets, so the order inside the brackets is retained.

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).